# Autodesk Revit Texture not included in viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Revit model loosing its texture avec svf translation

I tried to convert the file into fbx before translating it to svf
 revit file, , viewer translate from fbx

[viewer translate from rvt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjF7a.png)

[Screenshot of revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eDpY.png)

[viewer translate from fbx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDtin.png)

Answer (score 0):

To ensure custom material textures are applied, upload the RVT as a ZIP file with all texture files, then on `POST Job` request, specify the `rootFilename` and `compressedUrn:true`. [Learn more](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/).